# TFS2012 build server for SharePoint 2010 and 2013

Tags: sharepoint, team-foundation-server

Is there a way to use just one machine to configure a build server for both SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013? I'd like to know if anyone succeeded in such a task. We want to use PowerShell remoting for deployment.

So far I have found [a guide on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff622991.aspx) that goes in depth about configuring a build server for SP2013, but no mention of using it for both 2010 and 2013.